# "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function" - JavaScript object returns two types?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, typeerror

I am creating a site that uses HTML5 Canvas to draw geometry to the window. I have a "draw" function that I pass into a function that uses the requestAnimationFrame command like so:

```
function animate(drawMe) {
  var requestAnimationFrame =  
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      return setTimeout(callback, 10);
    };

  //draw the function that has been passed through
  drawMe();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

But check this out: when I call "drawMe();" in the above code, the function that has been passed through executes just fine, but also gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function".  If I include the line "console.log(typeof drawMe);" the console will print out TWO results, "function" and then "number".

So for instance I can have a very simple function like this:

```
drawloop1 = function() {
  //draws a Rect to my canvas context
  cxt.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
}
```

To make sure I'm doing it right, I run "console.log(typeof drawloop1);" and this prints "function", which is what I expect.  Then I pass it into my animation function like so:

```
animate(drawloop1);
```

Which seems quite straight-forward.  But as soon as it gets passed into "animate" it starts returning both "function" and "number".  It works as expected but ALSO throws a TypeError.  I have tried different variable names, afraid that there is a duplicate variable somewhere. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

...tells `requestAnimationFrame` to call the `animate()` function, but `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't know to pass `drawMe` as an argument. In fact what it passes as an argument *is* a number, a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, as [documented by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame#Parameters).

> *the console will print out TWO results, "function" and then "number".*

These aren't two results from the same call. It's one log from the successful first call, then a second log from a failed second call.

The *first* time `animate()` runs, when you call it directly, `drawMe` actually does reference a function that it can call. The *second* time `animate()` runs when called by `requestAnimationFrame()`, the `drawMe` argument is a number.

The first way that comes to mind to fix that is as follows:

```
function animate(drawMe) {
  var requestAnimationFrame =  
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      return setTimeout(callback, 10);
    };

  (function nextFrame() {
    drawMe();
    requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
  })();
}
```

That is, create a local function within `animate()` that has access to `animate()`'s arguments, and pass that local function to `requestAnimationFrame()`.